# Сохранить blob по url с расширением и именем файла

Tags: javascript, изображения, base64, blob

Что нужно добавить, чтобы сохраняло не как "Все файлы", а как image.png?

```
var img = document.getElementById("theimage");
img.onclick = function() {
// atob to base64_decode the data-URI
var image_data = atob(img.src.split(',')[1]);
// Use typed arrays to convert the binary data to a Blob
var arraybuffer = new ArrayBuffer(image_data.length);
var view = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
for (var i=0; i<image_data.length; i++) {
    view[i] = image_data.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
}
try {
    // This is the recommended method:
    var blob = new Blob([arraybuffer], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
} catch (e) {
    // The BlobBuilder API has been deprecated in favour of Blob, but older
    // browsers don't know about the Blob constructor
    // IE10 also supports BlobBuilder, but since the `Blob` constructor
    //  also works, there no need to add `MSBlobBuilder`.
    var bb = new (window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder);
    bb.append(arraybuffer);
    var blob = bb.getBlob('application/octet-stream'); // <-- Here the Blob
}

// Use the URL object to create a temporary URL
var url = (window.webkitURL || window.URL).createObjectURL(blob);
location.href = url; // <-- Download!
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Не переходим по адресу, а делаем ссылку:

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = (window.webkitURL || window.URL).createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = "image.png";
document.body.appendChild(link);
setTimeout(() => {
    link.click();
    documant.body.removeChild(link);
}, 33);
```